# Firefox scale image disappears

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm redesigning the layout of a theme, it works fine in Chrome and Safari, but the product's images disappear in Firefox on hover.

First I thought it was the scaling that caused the problem, but it does the job when it's scaling down(transform: scale(0.5);)

Another weird thing is that the other images in the sections below don't have such problem

Please help, thanks

Link to theme preview: http://hongyuan.theme.yurl.vip/
(The products with the problem are under the slideshow)

Comment: Please include an [MCVE] in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug indeed, particularly with the `text-overflow` property.

You are setting the wrapper's `<a>` element's font-size to `0`, you also say that text should not overflow and that overflowing text content should get replaced by an ellipsis `…`.
When you apply the `scale(1.1)`, the inner `<img>` element which is perceived as text because of the `display: inline` rule does overflow. And that's where the `text-overflow: ellipsis` algorithm kicks in and makes your image disappear:

```css
a {
  font-size: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
a > img {
  display: inline;
  transition: transform .3s linear;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
a > img:hover {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
a.no-ellipsis {
  text-overflow: clip;
}
```

```html
ellispis:
<a>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png">
</a>
no ellipsis:
<a class="no-ellipsis">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png">
</a>
```

To workaround that issue, you have several ways, including the one in the snippet (`text-overflow: clip`), or displaying your `<img>` as `block`, or setting your wrapper's `font-size` to `1px`, and probably others...

Comment: Wow thanks! I was just trying to clear the codes, but sadly coding is not really my specialty. I tried the `text-overflow` and `font-size` methods, both do the trick, but I'm going to use `text-overflow:clip` since `font-size:1px` seems to mess up with the height. Thanks again!